# What is the technical name of the syntactic feature "long foo = 12L;" style casting of harded-coded values in Java?

Tags: java, syntax, literals

Today, I was trying to cast a hard-coded value into a short and S did not work. So, I went to search for it, but I realized that I do not even know what this feature of Java's syntax is called. Is there a name for it? If not, is there at least a list of all of the possible ways to cast hard-coded numeric values?

**Epilouge**

After getting the answer "Literals", I was able to answer my question about shorts. In case you are wondering, there is no short literal in Java. You just have to explicitly cast it as so: `(short)12`.

Comment: As a side note, short (and byte) literals are possible additions to Java 7: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/000905.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are called *literals*.

From the [Primitive Data Types](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) page of The Java Tutorials:

> A literal is the source code
>   representation of a fixed value;
>   literals are represented directly in
>   your code without requiring
>   computation.

There's a list of literals that can be used in the [Primitive Data Types](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) page under the Literals section.

[Section 3.10: Literals](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10) of the [Java Language Specification, Third Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html) has a complete list as well.